# Stealth address in technical level

Tags: stealth-address

Lets say user `A` wants to send bitcoin to user `B` stealth address.

1. What is exactly user `B`'s stealth address? Is it his public key? Since User `A` needs to multiply his private key with user `B`'s public key based on [Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman) so I assume user `A` is receiving the complete point which is user `B`'s public key.
2. User `A` shoud calculate `PrivA * PublicB` which results in a coordinate. As far as I know this point will be used by multiplying it to the `publicB` and a nonce and that will be sent to the network. If what I am saying is correct, how can I multiply this coordinate with `PublicB` since both of them are points. Do we only get one axis of this point from the diffie hellman's calculation?

Comment: Very good question. Pybitcointools has [code](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools/blob/master/bitcoin/stealth.py) for it FWIW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is exactly user B's stealth address? Is it his public key?

In the simplest stealth address scheme, yes. The exact encoding depends on the implementation; DarkWallet's is described [in their wiki](https://wiki.unsystem.net/en/index.php/DarkWallet/Stealth#Address_format).

> how can I multiply this coordinate with PublicB since both of them are points?

Correct, `S = PrivA * PublicB = PrivB * PublicA` is a point. We want an integral shared secret. ECDH tells you to use the x coordinate of `S` as the shared secret, but in Bitcoin it's done differently. Instead `int(sha256(compress(S)))` is used:

1. serialize S in compressed form as per [SEC 1's Elliptic-Curve-Point-to-Octet-String Conversion](http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#page=16)
2. take its SHA-256 digest
3. interpret the result as a 256-bit big-endian integer

This integer, `c`, is then used by A to calculate a public key `PublicB + c*G` to which A spends, and by B to calculate its private key `(PrivB + c) * G` from which B can redeem (where `G` is the base point generator).

Note that there's a problem with this "simplest" scheme. The only way that B's wallet software can see if a UTXO is redeemable by B (to keep track of the wallet's balance) is by doing the math above, which requires `PrivB`. In other words, it makes watching-only wallets impossible (and cold wallets impractical).

One solution to this is to use one `PublicB`/`PrivB` pair for ECDH, but a different `PublicB2`/`PrivB2` pair for deriving the spend/redeem keys. Now you can keep `PrivB` in your watching-only wallet, and `PrivB2` in your cold wallet. On the down side, B's stealth address is now twice as long, containing both `PublicB` and `PublicB2`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your detailed answer.